# Как правильно написать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно и кратко (в объявлении) пригласить людей на угощение. Как написать: Угощение, Еда. Речь идет о конференции.

Answer (score 1):

Объявление.

Внимание: работает столовая. С 12.00 до 13.00 ждём участников конференции на обед. (Если утром - на завтрак, вечером - на ужин.) Или просто повесить расписание работы столовой, если будет завтрак, обед и ужин.

Comment: Да, второй вариант с расписанием  лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Например: "Уважаемые участники конференции, в перерыве приглашаем вас на фуршет. В холле второго этажа вам будут предложены чай, кофе, холодные закуски."

Comment: Ну, если только это конференции высокого класса, на обычных конференциях что-то фуршета ни разу не замечала, дороговато выйдет.Деловой а-ля фуршет-коктейль организуют в больших залах в перерывах совещаний или конгрессов, чтобы люди не только принимали пищу, но и общались, переходили от стойки к стойке,там предусмотрены и напитки, шампанское например.Если обычная деловая конференция, чаще всего - обед в столовой.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно: людей приглашают на конференцию или на угощения?